# In how much time will the NLP get trained?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am using the `dl4j-examples` from the Deeplearning project: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples
I am looking for the process to get completed, so that I can run other things with this module.

But I am looking for the process of Iteration to get completed. It is going on and on.

I do not understand why it is taking so long to train the NLP. I do not know how much time will it take to complete. If anyone have any idea please share and let me know how much time will it take to complete the process? If possible how I can make the process work faster?
My system configuration include :

```
Ram: 15.5 GiB
processor: Intel® Core™ i3-4150 CPU @ 3.50GHz × 4 
OS: 64-bit
```

What changes do I need to do in my code?
Here is the code for Word2VecSentimentRNN :

```
package org.deeplearning4j.examples.recurrent.word2vecsentiment;

import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream;
import org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip.GzipCompressorInputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.deeplearning4j.eval.Evaluation;
import org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader.WordVectorSerializer;
import org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.wordvectors.WordVectors;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.GradientNormalization;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.MultiLayerConfiguration;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.NeuralNetConfiguration;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.Updater;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.GravesLSTM;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.RnnOutputLayer;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.weights.WeightInit;
import org.deeplearning4j.optimize.listeners.ScoreIterationListener;
import org.nd4j.linalg.activations.Activation;
import org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray;
import org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.DataSet;
import org.nd4j.linalg.indexing.NDArrayIndex;
import org.nd4j.linalg.lossfunctions.LossFunctions;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
public class Word2VecSentimentRNN {

    /** Data URL for downloading */
    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz";
    /** Location to save and extract the training/testing data */
    public static final String DATA_PATH = FilenameUtils.concat(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "dl4j_w2vSentiment/");
    /** Location (local file system) for the Google News vectors. Set this manually. */
    public static final String WORD_VECTORS_PATH = "/PATH/TO/YOUR/VECTORS/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if(WORD_VECTORS_PATH.startsWith("/PATH/TO/YOUR/VECTORS/")){
            throw new RuntimeException("Please set the WORD_VECTORS_PATH before running this example");
        }

        //Download and extract data
        downloadData();

        int batchSize = 64;     //Number of examples in each minibatch
        int vectorSize = 300;   //Size of the word vectors. 300 in the Google News model
        int nEpochs = 1;        //Number of epochs (full passes of training data) to train on
        int truncateReviewsToLength = 256;  //Truncate reviews with length (# words) greater than this

        //Set up network configuration
        MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
            .updater(Updater.ADAM).adamMeanDecay(0.9).adamVarDecay(0.999)
            .regularization(true).l2(1e-5)
            .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
            .gradientNormalization(GradientNormalization.ClipElementWiseAbsoluteValue).gradientNormalizationThreshold(1.0)
            .learningRate(2e-2)
            .list()
            .layer(0, new GravesLSTM.Builder().nIn(vectorSize).nOut(256)
                .activation(Activation.TANH).build())
            .layer(1, new RnnOutputLayer.Builder().activation(Activation.SOFTMAX)
                .lossFunction(LossFunctions.LossFunction.MCXENT).nIn(256).nOut(2).build())
            .pretrain(false).backprop(true).build();

        MultiLayerNetwork net = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);
        net.init();
        net.setListeners(new ScoreIterationListener(1));

        //DataSetIterators for training and testing respectively
        WordVectors wordVectors = WordVectorSerializer.loadStaticModel(new File(WORD_VECTORS_PATH));
        SentimentExampleIterator train = new SentimentExampleIterator(DATA_PATH, wordVectors, batchSize, truncateReviewsToLength, true);
        SentimentExampleIterator test = new SentimentExampleIterator(DATA_PATH, wordVectors, batchSize, truncateReviewsToLength, false);

        System.out.println("Starting training");
        for (int i = 0; i < nEpochs; i++) {
            net.fit(train);
            train.reset();
            System.out.println("Epoch " + i + " complete. Starting evaluation:");

            //Run evaluation. This is on 25k reviews, so can take some time
            Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation();
            while (test.hasNext()) {
                DataSet t = test.next();
                INDArray features = t.getFeatureMatrix();
                INDArray lables = t.getLabels();
                INDArray inMask = t.getFeaturesMaskArray();
                INDArray outMask = t.getLabelsMaskArray();
                INDArray predicted = net.output(features, false, inMask, outMask);

                evaluation.evalTimeSeries(lables, predicted, outMask);
            }
            test.reset();

            System.out.println(evaluation.stats());
        }

        //After training: load a single example and generate predictions
        File firstPositiveReviewFile = new File(FilenameUtils.concat(DATA_PATH, "aclImdb/test/pos/0_10.txt"));
        String firstPositiveReview = FileUtils.readFileToString(firstPositiveReviewFile);

        INDArray features = test.loadFeaturesFromString(firstPositiveReview, truncateReviewsToLength);
        INDArray networkOutput = net.output(features);
        int timeSeriesLength = networkOutput.size(2);
        INDArray probabilitiesAtLastWord = networkOutput.get(NDArrayIndex.point(0), NDArrayIndex.all(), NDArrayIndex.point(timeSeriesLength - 1));

        System.out.println("\n\n-------------------------------");
        System.out.println("First positive review: \n" + firstPositiveReview);
        System.out.println("\n\nProbabilities at last time step:");
        System.out.println("p(positive): " + probabilitiesAtLastWord.getDouble(0));
        System.out.println("p(negative): " + probabilitiesAtLastWord.getDouble(1));

        System.out.println("----- Example complete -----");
    }

    private static void downloadData() throws Exception {
        //Create directory if required
        File directory = new File(DATA_PATH);
        if(!directory.exists()) directory.mkdir();

        //Download file:
        String archizePath = DATA_PATH + "aclImdb_v1.tar.gz";
        File archiveFile = new File(archizePath);
        String extractedPath = DATA_PATH + "aclImdb";
        File extractedFile = new File(extractedPath);

        if( !archiveFile.exists() ){
            System.out.println("Starting data download (80MB)...");
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(DATA_URL), archiveFile);
            System.out.println("Data (.tar.gz file) downloaded to " + archiveFile.getAbsolutePath());
            //Extract tar.gz file to output directory
            extractTarGz(archizePath, DATA_PATH);
        } else {
            //Assume if archive (.tar.gz) exists, then data has already been extracted
            System.out.println("Data (.tar.gz file) already exists at " + archiveFile.getAbsolutePath());
            if( !extractedFile.exists()){
                //Extract tar.gz file to output directory
                extractTarGz(archizePath, DATA_PATH);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Data (extracted) already exists at " + extractedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
    private static void extractTarGz(String filePath, String outputPath) throws IOException {
        int fileCount = 0;
        int dirCount = 0;
        System.out.print("Extracting files");
        try(TarArchiveInputStream tais = new TarArchiveInputStream(
                new GzipCompressorInputStream( new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(filePath))))){
            TarArchiveEntry entry;

            /** Read the tar entries using the getNextEntry method **/
            while ((entry = (TarArchiveEntry) tais.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                //System.out.println("Extracting file: " + entry.getName());

                //Create directories as required
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    new File(outputPath + entry.getName()).mkdirs();
                    dirCount++;
                }else {
                    int count;
                    byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + entry.getName());
                    BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,BUFFER_SIZE);
                    while ((count = tais.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
                        dest.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                    dest.close();
                    fileCount++;
                }
                if(fileCount % 1000 == 0) System.out.print(".");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n" + fileCount + " files and " + dirCount + " directories extracted to: " + outputPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using deeplearning4j so I can't make a proper answer, but it certainly wouldn't be surprising if training a neural network text classification model takes hours, especially as it seems that it's running on CPU instead of a GPU.

Comment: @Peteris What is a GPU .... ? Help me please. :P

Comment: So first things first: The fact you're doing deep learning and don't know what a gpu is terrifies me a bit. It comes up in most deep learning search results now a days. Please google nvidia gpu deep learning and do some reading. Anyways: the more cores the better. It definitely will take hours. Some ways to optimize training can be found here: http://deeplearning4j.org/benchmark

Comment: @AdamGibson That's was just for fun my friend.... :) I know what is GPU... I first thought of implement it on that but later thought to for first with the lab I have then to arrange GPU for myself.

Comment: Hah ok making sure :). I would just try to rent a big server on AWS or something if you want to train. It's  asad reality how long it takes. You can try to gague this in various ways with our UI by looking at things like batches per second: http://deeplearning4j.org/visualization